# Unity Oculus Link on Macbook

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

I would like to start developing some games/experiences for VR on the MacBook pro using Oculus Quest with the ability to enter the play mode during the development. I found that on OSX it's not possible and I would need a windows system. So I wonder if below would work.

I don't want to install Bootcamp on the Mac internal drive instead I was thinking about buying some external hard drive installing on it windows and all necessary drivers (Bootcamp, Oculus, Steam) and use it for development with Macbook. Would be this a viable option?? Would link work with this?
This also would grant me the ability to install games that I would like to play whenever I have access to the powerful PC with good GPU so there won't be any need to install all necessary software needed to run VR games on every machine. Just plug hard drive and play. But I don't know if there won't be any issue related to the graphics card drivers. As using it with a MacBook it would have AMD drivers and with any other VR ready PC probably Nvidia would be needed. Can I have both installed at the same time?

I would like to hear your voice before I would go and buy an external drive and try these scenarios.